# Como avisar ao compilador que se trata de um IEEE 754?

Tags: c

eu preciso de ajuda.

Tenho, por exemplo, um número em hexadecimal 0x41140000 que é 9.25 pelo padrão IEEE 754, mas como ler esse valor (contido em uma variável inteira) dando cast para um float e pegar o valor correto, ou seja, 9.25.

O que estão acontecendo é que após fazer a atribuição float = 0x41140000 eu recebo 1091829760.00 ao invés do valor desejado, o que até faz sentido, mas não é o que eu quero.

Alguém sabe um método de fazer isso?
desde já agradeço pela colaboração!

Comment: Relacionada (SOen): [How to convert an IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point to decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164620/how-to-convert-an-ieee-754-single-precision-binary-floating-point-to-decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você percebeu, se você tentar fazer um *typecast*, o *runtime* do C vai tentar efetuar a conversão como se o número fosse originalmente inteiro.  O que você precisa é do equivalente C do `reinterpret_cast<>` do C++.

Em C puro, isso se obtém com uma `union`; tendo um membro inteiro e um de ponto flutuante, basta escrever para o inteiro e ler o ponto flutuante:

```
float
reinterpret(uint32_t integer) {
    union { float f; uint32_t i; } u;
    u.i = integer;
    return u.f;
}
```

O processo inverso usa a mesma estrutura, mas lê o inteiro e escreve o ponto flutuante.

Comment: Era justamente o que eu estava procurando, Wtrmude. Muito obrigado!